# Passing a parameter between multiple intents triggering Dialogflow's Fulfillment

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a Dialogflow agent that I've setup with a web hook that is pulling info from a Firebase database.  I am trying to have different intents kick off different queries on the DB.  From the Welcome Intent the agent asks for a name that it will matching the DB (e.g. Hi it's nice to meet you? What is the name you looking for?).  From there the user is gives a name which is a response that triggers another intent called "name."  This intent has a parameter called  "agent.parameters.defaultName" which is passed into the fulfillment and used to query the DB.  Below is the webhook kicks off the following script:

```
});
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {

const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + 
JSON.stringify(request.headers));
console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

//function to request bio info on the db
function handleData(agent) {
const congressName = agent.parameters.congressName;
return admin.database().ref().once("value").then((snapshot) => {
var nameInfo = snapshot.child('Name/' + congressName + '/profile').val(); 
agent.add(nameInfo + "\n  \n Tell me the first and last name of the next 
person you'd like to learn about. Or you can say Twitter to get this 
individual's Twitter info.");
});
 }

//Function to return the name's tweet info
function handleTweet(agent) {
const congressName = agent.parameters.congressName;
return admin.database().ref().once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  var nameTweet = snapshot.child('Name/' + congressName + '/twitter_handle').val(); 
  agent.add(nameTweet);
});
}
// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent 
name
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('name', handleData);
intentMap.set('name - custom', handleTweet);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

This returns the bio and prompts the user to say another name or say twitter to pull the twitter info.

If the user says Twitter I'd like for another intent to be triggered.  This Intent would also have a fulfillment that would call the DB, but this time it'd pull the Twitter info.  Where I'm having an issue is I can't get this intent to trigger the fulfillment.  I'm wondering if my parameter is in the right section or if I need to figure out how to pass it to the Twitter intent.  I'm not sure where I'm off.

Below are the intents:

```
//Name intent
{
  "id": "0c7bd173-e7fe-4bb4-9b87-7b94624ceb4e",
  "name": "name",
  "auto": true,
  "contexts": [],
  "responses": [{
    "resetContexts": false,
    "action": "congressName",
    "affectedContexts": [{
      "name": "Name",
      "parameters": {},
      "lifespan": 5
    }],
    "parameters": [{
      "id": "a79559d6-d3db-4b37-b681-174fce8bc58c",
      "required": true,
      "dataType": "@sys.any",
      "name": "congressName",
      "value": "$congressName",
      "prompts": [{
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "What is the proper first and last name of the person you 
  are looking for info on?"
      }],
      "isList": false
    }],
    "messages": [{
      "type": 0,
      "lang": "en",
      "speech": []
    }],
    "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
    "speech": []
  }],
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookUsed": true,
  "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
  "lastUpdate": 1535995990,
  "fallbackIntent": false,
  "events": []
 }
 [{
    "id": "a14768b0-c64d-4a63-9ccb-d9452b74ed21",
    "data": [{
      "text": "tammy duckworth",
      "alias": "congressName",
      "meta": "@sys.any",
      "userDefined": false
    }],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0,
    "updated": 1535223341
  },
  {
    "id": "520acfc8-102b-4e14-9342-54678e9f6940",
    "data": [{
      "text": "tom cotton",
      "alias": "congressName",
      "meta": "@sys.any",
      "userDefined": false
    }],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0,
    "updated": 1535223341
  }
]
//Twitter intent

"id": "78330811-d692-4c70-adb2-3130b608d46f",
"name": "twitter",
"auto": true,
"contexts": [],
"responses": [{
  "resetContexts": false,
  "action": "",
  "affectedContexts": [],
  "parameters": [{
    "id": "7acd4cb2-9cd7-4c2a-b5aa-2981ee25acf4",
    "dataType": "@congressName",
    "name": "congressName",
    "value": "$congressName",
    "isList": false
  }],
  "messages": [{
    "type": 0,
    "lang": "en",
    "speech": []
  }],
  "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
  "speech": []
}],
"priority": 500000,
"webhookUsed": true,
"webhookForSlotFilling": false,
"lastUpdate": 1535996186,
"fallbackIntent": false,
"events": []
}
[{
    "id": "4f099a33-74c6-4832-acd1-815aca6605f2",
    "data": [{
        "text": "Susan Collins",
        "alias": "congressName",
        "meta": "@congressName",
        "userDefined": false
      },
      {
        "text": " Twitter",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0,
    "updated": 1535996186
  },
  {
    "id": "f775749a-56fd-410d-a167-174e6eb03ddf",
    "data": [{
        "text": "twitter ",
        "userDefined": false
      },
      {
        "text": "@congress",
        "alias": "congressName",
        "meta": "@congressName",
        "userDefined": true
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0,
    "updated": 1535238371
  }
]
```

Comment: can you show the two intent you have created for Name and Twitter?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Abhinav!  I've updated my question with the mentioned intents.

Comment: instead of JSON format, screenshot would be better for intents.